# Cannot shift plot in Tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I have nodes that are placed at specific positions in my Tikz picture, and I would like to put a plot next to it. To do this, I am using a shifted `scope`. However, when I change the shift values, nothing changes.

This is code with a simplified version of my problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node at (2.7, -3.6) {Test};

\begin{scope}[x=4,y=1cm, shift={(3,-3.6)}]
    \tikz \draw[color=orange, domain=-2:2] plot (\x,{exp(-\x * \x)}) {};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Could you provide some guidance on how to fix this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing `\tikz` gets the job done :)

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node at (2.7, -3.6) {Test};
\begin{scope}[x=4,y=1cm, shift={(3,-3.6)}]
    \draw[color=orange, domain=-2:2] plot (\x,{exp(-\x * \x)}) {};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

As @M. Al Jumaily already mentioned, the `\tikz` inside `scope` is incorrect (nesting `tikz` environments is always a bad idea).

Also, some of the packages in your preambel are not necessary (`amsmath` and `pgfplots`). Finally, one can avoid the `scope` environment. Therefore, I suggest the following simplification that makes the job you need.

#### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=4,y=1cm]
\draw[color=orange,domain=-2:2,smooth]
    plot (\x,{exp(-\x * \x)})
    node[right,black,xshift=1cm] {Test};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```